# Where can I find online test page for testing manual sql injection

Tags: sql-injection

So, I'm writing my final thesis and I need online web page so I can test that page for sql injection manually! Does anyone knows any web page that's safe for testing it? Thx

Answer (score 0):

You can find many webpages vulnerable to SQL Injection by using Google Dorks.
Choose anyone that doesn't concern you legally.
Or you can perform that in any local test environment like Damn Vulnerable Web Application (DVWA).
One of the most favourite site of hackers you can test is http://bbss.com.pk/index.php?id=483

Happy Hacking!!